# Single PHP save page

Tags: php, variables, save

Hopefully someone can advise?

I have 3 .PHP pages numbered

page1.php
page2.php
page3.php

At the moment, I have to hard code three save .PHP pages as called:

save1.php
save2.php
save3.php

My current code that saves to a MySQL database:

```
$q1 = $_POST["q1"];
$q2 = $_POST["q2"];
$q3 = $_POST["q3"];
$q4 = $_POST["q4"];
$q5 = $_POST["q5"];
$q6 = $_POST["q6"];
$q7 = $_POST["q7"];
$q8 = $_POST["q8"];


$proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tresults_bh_main (respondent_id, ip, browser, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "issiiiiiiii", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8);
```

I manually have to change the q1, q2, q3 etc to match the q's on pages 1, 2 and 3.  What I would like to do is have a single .PHP save page that can used for all of my pages (make sense?).

What I cannot get to grips with is how to code the .PHP save page so that it uses variables instead on me hard coding it.

I have an array which stores the following information:  **$qs['questions']** - stores, for example q1, q2, q3, q4 etc

If anyone can help, much appreciated.

Homer.

Comment: Can you more explain what you want? 
Is this maybe what you want? 
http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/8069/unled1fb.png

Comment: Ok. Where are the differences between save1.php and save2.php and save3.php? 
You have same variables with same `$_POST[];`, same database, same table, same INSERT operation.

Comment: The q numbers vary from page to page, therefore all parts with a q num will vary, as well as the '?, ?, ' and 'issiiii' parts.  All vary on depending on the number of questions.  Make sense?

Comment: Only what u need to change is variable names. U can't make same save.php with variables which have same names three times. PHP will save only last statment of variables. 
Just change variables names for example: 
Variable 1 from page 1: `$q1_p1 = $_POST["q1_p1"];`
Variable 1 from page 2: `$q1_p2 = $_POST["q1_p2"];`

And make one INSERT to table, or one INSERT for answers from first page, and two UPDATE table for pages 1 and 2. Understood?

Comment: Or you can use same variable names, but u need to add one hidden field for page1, one for page2 and one for page3. And in save.php make if else statements for hidden fileds. 
For example: `If` hidden field name is 1 variables use datas. And make sql insert. `elseif` hidden field name is 2 same `elseif` hidden filedn name is 3 same `else` show up some error text. If you need code directly request it here. That is simple to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very pretty but should do what you want, perhaps it's something you can get ideas from.

```
$list_variable = '';
$list_values = '';
$str = 'iss';
$array_data = array();

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $array_data[] = &$respondent_id;
    $array_data[] = &$ip;
    $array_data[] = &$browser;

    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
        if (!preg_match('/^q\d+$/', $k))
            continue;

        $str .= 'i';
        $list_variable .= ", $k";
        $list_values .= ", ?";
        $array_data[] = &$_POST[$k];
    }

    if ($list_variable != '') {
        array_unshift($array_data, $str);

        $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tresults_bh_main (respondent_id, ip, browser $list_variable) VALUES (?, ?, ? $list_values);");
        call_user_func_array(array($proc, 'bind_param'), $array_data);
        //$proc->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of the regexp (preg_match) you could have an array of valid variable names and use in_array

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest u to make the 'q' as a part of form as hidden, so that you can collect it in the mysql action page and just insert it.

detailed answer :

use another element like

```
<input type='text' name='pageNumber' value='1'>  here value will be 1/2/3 depending on your page number. then create a single save.php page and there collect the variable using
```

$_POST['pageNumber'] ... hope its clear now. This is as per i understood your question.

Comment: He said to you, same what I said to you above in comments. Make different variable names. `$_POST[q1_p1];` this q1_p1 will be name in html part of code etc... Your input must have name q1_p1 to getting work `$_POST[q1_p1];` :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but why not starting by making a loop?

```
function DoSomething($respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $count)
{
    settype($count, 'integer');
    if ($count < 1)
    {
        throw new Exception('The $count argument cannot be less than one.');
    }

    $queryVariables = '';
    $queryParams = array('issiiiiiiii', $respondent_id, $ip, $browser);

    $q = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
        $q[$i] = $_POST['q' . $i];
        $queryVariables .= ', q' . $i;
        $queryParams[] = $q[$i];
    }

    $query = 'insert into tresults_bh_main (respondent_id, ip, browser' . $queryVariables . ') values (' . str_repeat('?, ', $count - 1) . '?);';

    $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    execSQL($proc, $queryParams);
}

DoSomething($respondent_id, $ip, $browser, 8);
```

Where `execSQL` is a method taken from [a user contributed note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#100879) of PHP documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hacking apart your POST index keys, You can use multidimensional arrays as your post variables.

So.....

`<input type="text" name="question[page1][q1]" />`

Is read via

`$_POST['page1']['q1']`

That would be the easier than trying to split up the keys.

if you need to know what page to draw from you can check:

`if (empty($_POST['page1']) {`